# Coq: performing inversion on Prop for Set when there is only one case

Tags: coq, dependent-type, coq-tactic, ltac

Suppose I have some programming language, with a "has type" relation and a "small step" relation.

```
Inductive type : Set :=
| Nat : type
| Bool : type.

Inductive tm : Set :=
| num : nat -> tm
| plus : tm -> tm -> tm
| lt : tm -> tm -> tm
| ifthen : tm -> tm -> tm -> tm.

Inductive hasType : tm -> type -> Prop :=
| hasTypeNum :
    forall n, hasType (num n) Nat
| hasTypePlus:
    forall tm1 tm2,
      hasType tm1 Nat ->
      hasType tm2 Nat ->
      hasType (plus tm1 tm2) Nat
| hasTypeLt:
    forall tm1 tm2,
      hasType tm1 Nat ->
      hasType tm2 Nat ->
      hasType (lt tm1 tm2) Bool
| hasTypeIfThen:
    forall tm1 tm2 tm3,
      hasType tm1 Bool ->
      hasType tm2 Nat ->
      hasType tm3 Nat ->
      hasType (ifthen tm1 tm2 tm3) Nat.

Inductive SmallStep : tm -> tm -> Prop :=
  ...

Definition is_value (t : tm) := ...
```

The key detail here is that for each term variant, there's only one possible HasType variant that could possible match.

Suppose then that I want to prove a progress lemma, but that I also want to be able to extract an interpreter from this.

```
Lemma progress_interp: 
  forall tm t, 
  hasType tm t -> 
  (is_value tm = false) -> 
  {tm2 | SmallStep tm tm2}.
intro; induction tm0; intros; inversion H.
```

This gives the error `Inversion would require case analysis on sort Set which is not allowed for inductive definition hasType.`

I understand why it's doing this: `inversion` performs case analysis on a value of sort `Prop`, which we can't do since it gets erased in the extracted code.

But, because there's a one-to-one correspondence between the term variants and type derivation rules, we don't actually have to perform any analysis at runtime.

Ideally, I could apply a bunch of lemmas that look like this:

```
plusInv: forall e t, hasType e t ->
  (forall e1 e2, e = plus e1 e2 -> hasType e1 Nat /\ hasType e2 Nat ).
```

where there would be a lemma like this for each case (or a single lemma that's a conjunction of these cases).

I've looked at `Derive Inversion` but it doesn't seem to do what I'm looking for here, though maybe I'm not understanding it correctly.

Is there a way to do this sort of "case analysis where there's only one case?" Or to get the equalities implied by the `Prop` proof, so that I can only write the possible cases in my extracted interpreter? Can deriving these lemmas be automated, with Ltac or a Deriving mechanism?

Comment: I edited the statement of `plus_inv`: the previous statement was not acceptable to Coq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lemma `plus_inv` can be obtained by a case analysis on type `tm` instead of a case analysis on type `hasType`.

```
Lemma plus_inv : forall e t, hasType e t ->
  (forall e1 e2, e = plus e1 e2 -> hasType e1 Nat /\ hasType e2 Nat ).
Proof.
intros e; case e; try (intros; discriminate).
intros e1 e2 t h; inversion h; intros e5 e6 heq; inversion heq; subst; auto.
Qed.
```

The proof of your main objective `progress_interp` can probably be performed
by induction ont the structure of `tm` as well.  This tantamounts to writing your interpreter directly as a gallina recursive function.

Your question has a second part: can this be automated.  The answer is yes, probably.  I suggest using either the [template-coq](https://template-coq.github.io/template-coq/) package or the [elpi](https://github.com/LPCIC/coq-elpi) package for this.  Both packages are available as opam packages.

Comment: Thanks. The key for me really is to automate it, since I'm dealing with a language with many more cases than the toy one I've used here. I'll take a look at Template Coq, it seems very useful!

Answer (score 1):

I think `eexists` will do the trick: the existential variable should be filled in at some point during the proof in the sigma type (where you can freely use `inversion` on the `hasType` hypothesis).

Comment: I've tried this in the past, but often get problems where unification fails because the solution for the existential isn't in scope for it. Is there a common workaround for this?

Comment: I think `eexists` is not the answer.  If that did work, then the consistency of the logical system (also with respect to extraction) would be at risk.